# Rails - get objects belong to other objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

appreciate if you help me. I'm using rails 4.2.

I have 2 models - Epoch and Event. Every epoch has many events.

I want to make list with events for every epoch:

```
<% @epoches.each do |epoch| %>
    <div><%= epoch.main_title %> : </div>
    <% @events.each do |event| %>
        <div><%= event.title %></div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

my epoches_controller.rb looks like:

```
def epochline
    @epoches = Epoch.all
    @events = Epoch.find(params[:id]).event.all
end
```

When i call in console "Epoch.find(1).events.all" it works amazing, but web-server return error - "Couldn't find Epoch with 'id'=". What am i doing wrong? How can I edit my controller to solve this problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the `@events = Epoch.find(params[:id]).event.all` line in the controller and the view should be this.

```
<% @epoches.each do |epoch| %>
    <div><%= epoch.main_title %> : </div>
    <% epoch.events.each do |event| %>
        <div><%= event.title %></div>
    <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Edit: You can eager load events by doing `@epoches = Epoch.includes(:events)` in your controller. That will cache both epochs and events and also will prevent doing sql queries in your view

Comment: also, you can eager load events by doing `@epoches = Epoch.includes(:events)` and avoid doing sql queries (`epoch.events`) in your view

Comment: @mr_sudaca I would upvote your comment 4 more times if I could. Views should not query the database and especially when performing n+1 queries.

Comment: Good point, @mr_sudaca do you want to propose an edit with that included in the answer and then I will accept?

Comment: edit added, first edit :), so don't know if it's valid for SO